# Java Socket server side cannot read incoming line of text in play framework application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, playframework

So I'm having some serious problems with Java's server side socket, which accepts connection, but it can't read anything from `BufferedReader`, which I have put to read the text stream from socket connection. Code for my threads `run()`, which I'm creating and running at the first time when any page is loaded.

```
public void run() {

    try{
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(4100);

        System.out.println("New tcp socket created");

        Socket socket = s.accept();
        System.out.println("New tcp update connection established.");
        InputStream din = socket.getInputStream();
        PrintWriter outp = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));
        System.out.println("Streams created");
        String inputline = "nothing yet...";
        outp.println("hello from server");
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Got input from client:" + inputline);
            inputline = in.readLine();
            if(inputline == null || inputline.equals("exit")){

                break;
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Updater thread exits.");
}
```

This prints out everything properly, except for Got input from client: + what ever my client sends with `PrintWriter` which outputs to a socket.

Client side example:

```
Socket s = new Socket(serverip, serverDownloadsUpdatePort);

OutputStream dout = s.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter outp = new PrintWriter(dout);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

System.out.println(in.readLine());//This prints out properly, what server sends to      client
outp.println("test connection");
outp.println("Can you hear me?");
outp.println("exit");
s.close();
```

Comment: show your client code.

Comment: @jtahlborn There you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I forgot to set PrintWriter as auto flushable at client side and thats why it didn't work becouse stream didn't got flushed at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Your client may not be sending end-of-line characters along with its input, causing your server to wait indefinitely at "in.readLine()".

The Javadoc for BufferedReader's readLine method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) says: "Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed." Make sure that your client is sending input that conforms to this rule.

I was able to see client input using your server with the following client Runnable (but only if I include the "\n"):

```
public void run() {
            try{
                Socket writeSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4100);
                PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(writeSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.write("Hello there!\n");
                out.flush();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

EDIT: When using println as in the submitter's client example, you don't need to worry about adding "\n", but you do need to flush the socket. One way to make sure this happens is by setting autoFlush=true in the PrintWriter constructor.

Comment: This looks pretty interesting. I have used this kind of socket setup before with BufferedReader and PrintWriter. Then I called println() on sending side and readLine() at recieving side without problems. Another thing is that when server sends string to client using printl() client is able to read it without any problems using readLine().

Comment: Yes, as you pointed out in your answer, in this case the only thing that was missing was setting autoFlush=true on the socket.